# How do I programmatically transfer file to iOS device using iTunes file share?

Tags: ios, itunes

I want to create a software program which basically can transfer files to iOS device using iTunes file sharing. Now the iOS part is done, I created a iOS app which allows me to drag and drop files from my desktop to the app sandbox. Question is how do I programmatically achieve this?

Please point a direction for me.

Answer (score 0):

Ray Wenderlich has a great (as always) tutorial for that -

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1948/how-integrate-itunes-file-sharing-with-your-ios-app

Comment: The question was how to do the file transfer programmatically. This tutorial only answers how to integrate file sharing in the app, which the asker has already done.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting itunes or using it is not a simple task but I recommend you a clever and easier solution:
Implement a simple webserver on your iOS app. Write a windows application which will connect to your iOS app through wifi network. Then transfer the necessary files this way: you will send a file to you app, then your app should save it in documents directory,